# How to hide parent div if child div has no value

Tags: html, css, tumblr

This is a very minute detail, as it is not a problem when there ARE posts obviously; but when the theme has no posts, the page displays a white border with no padding or content. I'd like to hide that completely if there are no posts.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
{Block:posts}
...
{/Block:posts}
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container:empty{
    display:none;
}

#container{
    position:absolute;
    border:5px solid white;
    border-radius:3px;
    display:inline-block
     background:#155484;
     max-height:497px;
     width:547px;
     overflow-y:scroll;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     margin-left:43%;
     margin-right:15%;
     margin-top:3%;
     margin-bottom:5%;
}

#content{
    margin:5px;
    margin-right:0px;
    background:#7995d6;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    width:auto;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:monospace;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

I know that display:none doesn't actually work, but I'm lost on where to start. Also, I'd like to stick to CSS or HTML if possible; I don't have a clue how to use anything else.

Comment: Apply the borders on the #content element instead, then you can set `#content:empty { display: none}`

Comment: The `:empty` pseudo-class will match white space also, You need to be sure the element is completely empty, Also move it from the `#container` to `#content`